# Есть ли в С# WPF string resources файл?

Tags: c#

Есть ли возможность поместить все стринги в отдельный файл и присваевать его значения как ресурс в каждом месте где нужно?

Comment: да, все также как и в других типах проектов

Comment: @yolosora я не работал никогда с c# wpf можете дать пример как определить файл и как его использовать?

Comment: Не забывайте пожалуйста ставить метку WPF в свои вопросы! Ну а по самому вопросу - смотря как вы собираетесь эти строки использовать и для чего они вам. Вы можете все строки разместить [в XAML](https://habr.com/ru/post/256193/), а можете использовать [resx](https://habr.com/ru/post/86778/), можете вовсе написать [нечто свое](https://habr.com/ru/post/274477/), что будет разбирать нужный вам файл (xml/ini/json) и выдавать по ключу нужную строку (есть готовые решения, например [EasyLocalization](https://github.com/zHaytam/EasyLocalization)).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ чувсвтуется, что все эти примеры заточены под локализацию, то есть для работы с языками, мне вроде как подходит, но моя основная идея не совсем в возможности смены языка, а просто файл для хранения всех строк. Чтоб не приходилось по всему проекту хардкодить строки, а все написать в файл и по ключу получать. В целом пример с resx мне подходит, только я не уверен, что это то, что мне нужно.

Comment: Ну локализация и работает по сути с сохраненными в файле строками, поэтому дал примеры их реализации (можете поискать что либо еще, куда копать я показал). Вообще подобное можно решить уймой способов, я например делаю JSON файл, который десериализуется в некий синглтон при старте приложения и уже из него получаю данные (он у меня обычно для настроек пользователя используется). Если именно брать стандартные вещи, то это `.resx`, некий файл ресурсов, который содержит в себе например строки.